# Kernel K nearest neighbours with sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, k-nearest-neighbour, sparse, data-preprocessing

I have a big sparse matrix (around 5 million of lines, 20 000 predictors), and I would like to run a kernelized k-NN on it. However, I don't know how to scale the data properly.

So far, I have scaled my data to the unit sphere (all my entries are nonnegative), and my k-NN was working perfectly.

(Note that centering and reducing the data with sparse matrix is problematic : [Feature scaling for non-negative sparse data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153832/feature-scaling-for-non-negative-sparse-data) - and I cannot drop sparsity at all)

Now I would like to use a polynomial kernel : 
$K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = (1 + \langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \rangle)^d$

I end up working with the following distance : $d^2(f(x), f(y)) = K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}) - 2K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) + K(\mathbf{y} ,\mathbf{y})$

Now, say $d=2$ and I constrain my data to the unit sphere in the first place. Then $K(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y})=K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=4$ and $K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ becomes a monotonic function of $ \langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \rangle$, producing the same classification, regardless of $d$.

Now, if I don't scale the data at all, it will not be scaled in the represented space and I expect poor performance (since my classification will be driven by features with high order of magnitudes only).

The question is, how should I pre-process my data ? Is there a transformation of the kernel that would mimic the pre-processing for me ?